# Migrating from Network.HTTP.Enumerator to Network.HTTP.Conduit

Tags: haskell, yesod, conduit, http-conduit

I don't know why my code breaks. At first I thought it was because `parseURL` gives `[]` for the `requestHeaders`. Okay, so maybe I just need to tell it what the resquestHeaders should be. Well, I examined the `requestHeaders` generated from my old, working code. It too, returns a `[]`. So now I am out of ideas. Below is the old working code, followed my things I have been trying in GHCi with with new conduits based library.

```
captureRawJson :: IO Response
captureRawJson = do
    nManager <- newManager
    jRequest <- parseUrl url :: (IO (Request IO))
    jResponse <- httpLbsRedirect jRequest nManager
    closeManager nManager
    return jResponse
```

the above works fine, here's what I have been trying to do while migrating, and the error I receive.

```
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit> nManager <- newManager def
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit> jRequest <- parseUrl "https://10.69.69.1/cgi-bin/qaLinkEditor.cgi?json=1" :: (IO (Request IO))
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit> let response = httpLbs jRequest nManager
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit Control.Monad.Trans.Resource> runResourceT response
*** Exception: error unexpected packet: Handshake [ServerHelloDone]
```

So as you can see, it's almost exactly the same code. So I would like feedback on what has changed, and what I should be looking at more closely. Also, how can I examine the http headers being sent back and forth between my client code and the server?

Comment: The error message is coming from tls, not from http-conduit, so I'm not sure it's really a change in http-conduit. Can you try recompiling http-enumerator against the newest tls package and see what happens?

Comment: I only have tls 0.8.5 (the latest afaik) installed, so that has to be what http-enumerator built against.

Comment: @Michael - Here's the status. I upgraded to 0.7.2.5 of http-enumerator, which removed the impetus to migrate to http-conduits. So there's no real urgency. However, I'd like to play with the cool kids and figure out how to get http-conduits working if possible.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem against a public server, then we can try and debug it. But we can't test against a private server.

Comment: Okay, that will take some time to pull off, but I think I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was solved with some changes in the tls packages. I just released http-conduit 1.2.5, please have a look and see if it solves the problem.

If you still get an error message, it could be that the SSL cert doesn't match the hostname you're connecting to.