# Package conflict between http-enumerator and several new yesod packages

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

This problem is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154504/migrating-from-network-http-enumerator-to-network-http-conduit#comment11514223_9154504). I was prompted to try to migrate from http-enumerator to http-conduit because of this package version conflict.

```
package http-enumerator-0.7.2 requires failure-0.1.2
package yesod-core-0.10.0 requires failure-0.2.0
package xml-conduit-0.5.2 requires failure-0.2.0
package http-conduit-1.2.3 requires failure-0.2.0
package hamlet-0.10.7.1 requires failure-0.2.0
```

It may be the migration will take some time, so I come back to this problem in hopes there is a solution. Is there a way to let these separate versions of `failure` be in the same cabal package?

The alternative is *gulp* using curl bindings. I have found that package brings with it behavior that is sometimes bizarre.

Comment: Can you use `http-enumerator-0.7.2.5`? It is compatible with `failure-0.2.0`. Or perhaps you can modify the 0.7.2 package to use 0.2.0.

Comment: why not upgrade your version of http-enumerator?  That latest version also depends on failure >= 0.1 && < 0.3.

Comment: @n.m I'm face-palming over here. For some reason I thought 7.2 was the final version of http-enumerator. I upgraded to 0.7.2.5 and the conflict has been resolved.